# Perform scale operation on QWidget and its children

Tags: c++, qt, scale

I need to perform a scale operation on a `QWidget` and have this filter down to all it's child widgets.

Elsewhere in the application I have `QGraphicsView` objects which use a `QGraphicsProxyWidget` to perform the same operation with a `setScale()` call but on this particular widget I am **unable to use a QGraphicsView** as it contains a **VLC video** which won't display within a `QGraphicsView`.

Any suggestions on **how to scale a QWidget** and ensure the effect is propagated?